# GCE won't keep my script running

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I've tried using:

```
screen; main.py 
nohup python main.py &
tmux; python main.py
python main.py & disown
```

For all of these options the script stops running after about 1/2 hour after I exit the SSH. I can't seem to find any info why this is happening and it's baffling!

I'm running on GCE on a standard CPU. The CPU runs at %100 w/ the script, but then dips to 0% about 1/2 after I exit the ssh connection. 
(when running on a local terminal the script runs to completion which normally takes several hours)

(after some more reading, i'm questioning if what I really need is a daemon, but why? Every answer I come across on the subject suggests the options I've already tried should work )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking in /var/log/syslog is giving me the reason: out of memory. The kernel is killing my script for that reason.